# Error using PubSub emulator with Spring Cloud GCP (UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found)

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I'm trying to use Spring Cloud GCP PubSub to communicate to a PubSub emulator.

Dependency:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also I have this `application.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host=localhost:8081
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id=test
```

After starting an integration test to check if a topic exists, I get this error:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnimplementedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/GetTopic
```

Stacktrace cause:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnimplementedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/GetTopic
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:65) ~[gax-1.35.1.jar:1.35.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.35.1.jar:1.35.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.35.1.jar:1.35.1]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-1.35.1.jar:1.35.1]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[api-common-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1123) ~[guava-20.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435) ~[guava-20.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:900) ~[guava-20.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:811) ~[guava-20.0.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:675) ~[guava-20.0.jar:?]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:507) ~[grpc-stub-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:482) ~[grpc-stub-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusStatsModule.java:678) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor$1$1.onClose(CensusTracingModule.java:397) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:459) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:63) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:546) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:467) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:584) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.16.1.jar:1.16.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
```

The code used:

```java
package br.com.stilingue.pubsub;

import br.com.stilingue.pubsub.PubSubApplication;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubProperties;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PubSubApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PubSubApplication.class})
public class PubSubApplicationTest {
  @Autowired GcpPubSubProperties properties;
  @Autowired PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;
  @Autowired PubSubAdmin pubSubAdmin;

  @Test
  public void testTopicIsNull() {
    Assert.assertNull(this.pubSubAdmin.getTopic("topic-name"));
  }
}
```

My searchs didn't found any reason for this code to not work.

Any tips?